# unable to run the login test using selenium BDD frame work

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, bdd

Feature: Test the login function

Scenario Outline: Test login function
Given User open the Browser and navigated
Then User enter  and 
And Click the login button
Then User navigated to FB home page

```
Examples: 
  | username |  | password |
  | asd      |  |      123 |
```

Error
Given User open the Browser and navigated # stepDef.Testlogin.user_open_the_browser_and_navigated()
Then User enter asd and 123               # stepDef.Testlogin.user_enter_username_and_password(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [User enter (.*) and (.*)] is defined with 2 parameters at 'stepDef.Testlogin.user_enter_username_and_password(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'.
However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.
Step text: User enter asd and 123

Runner class file.

public class Testlogin {
static WebDriver driver;

```
@Given("User open the Browser and navigated")
public void user_open_the_browser_and_navigated() throws IOException {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();    
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
}
@Then("User enter (.*) and (.*)")
public void user_enter_username_and_password (String username,String password)  {
     System.out.println("The cell value is: "+username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(username);  
    
    //System.out.println("The cell value is: "+password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(password);   
}
@Then("Click the login button")
public void click_the_login_button() {
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Then("User navigated to FB home page")
public void user_navigated_to_fb_home_page() {
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There you have used `Scenario Outlie` with `Examples` but you have not passed the same the cucumber step but you have written the arguments for the same.

You gherkin should be like.

```
  Scenario Outline: Test login function
    Given User open the Browser and navigated
    When User enter "<username>" and "<password>"
    And Click the login button
    Then User navigated to FB home page
    Examples: 
      | username |  | password |
      | asd      |  |      123 |
```

Step Definitions should be like.

```
@Given("User open the Browser and navigated")
public void user_open_the_browser_and_navigated() throws IOException {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();    
    options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
    driver =new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
}
@When("User enter (.*) and (.*)")
public void user_enter_and(String username,String password)  {
     System.out.println("The cell value is: "+username);
    driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys(username);  
    
    //System.out.println("The cell value is: "+password);
    driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys(password);   
}
@And("Click the login button")
public void click_the_login_button() {
    driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
}

@Then("User navigated to FB home page")
public void user_navigated_to_fb_home_page() {
   
}
```

Comment: sir ,i already passed the arguments as you mentioned above but when i copy paste the steps it was rearrenged.here the problem is step2 has a error ie : io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Step [User enter (.*) and (.*)] is defined with 2 parameters at 'stepDef.Testlogin.user_enter_username_and_password(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)'.
However, the gherkin step has 0 arguments.

Comment: code updated for the step definitions check now for step `When User enter "<username>" and "<password>"`

Comment: The problems is i forgot to add ^ and $ symbol in step defintion file.